# EF.Core load all records that don't have a related record in other table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible in Entity Framework Core (or 7), to load all records from a table that don't have a related record in the other table?

In my case I have a Customers table and an Contracts table. Customers can have 0 to N contracts. In this particular use case I would like to query all Customers that don't have a contract.

```
**Customer Table:**

CustomerId | Name
---------- | ----------
1          | Apple
2          | Google
3          | Microsoft

**Contracts Table:**

| ContractId | CustomerId | StartDate  | EndDate    |
| ---------: | ---------: | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1          | 2          | 01-01-2016 | 01-01-2018 |
| 2          | 3          | 01-01-2016 | 01-01-2018 |
```

In this case I would like the query to return only one object containing the Apple customer.

In SQL I would do something like this:

```
select cust.CustomerId, cust.Name
  from dbo.Customers as cust
    left outer join dbo.Contracts as contr
      on cust.CustomerId = contr.CustomerId
  where contr.ContractId is null;
```

How can I translate this to a EF query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a linq query to achieve what you want like this (independent of the EF version):

```
var result = yourContext
    .Customers
    .Where(x => !yourContext.Contracts.Any(y => x.Id == y.CustomerId));
```

Of course I assumed that in your customer entity `CustomerId` is called `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property `List<Contracts>` in the `Customer` class and you can get the customers with no contracts by the following query:

```
var customersWithZeroContract = db.Customers.Where(c => c.Contracts.Count()  == 0);
```